# How to change themes of jqgrid on selection in a combo box

Tags: jquery, css, jqgrid

I am getting a theme from the jQuery UI Theme roller, and now I want to change the theme according to a selection from a combo box.
Please Suggest me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This link may help you [Dynamic ThemeRoller](http://midnightprogrammer.net/post/change-page-themes-dynamically-using-jquery-theme-roller/).

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ThemeRoller').themeswitcher();
});
```